# QProcess limitations assistance

Tags: qt, batch-file, qt4

Hello all I have come around a limitation of QProcess. If I use '|' then it skips the process but I need that '|' character in my process

Suppose I have a exe and I need '|' in its arguments list then it doesn't work because command prompt takes '|' as OR. and therefore it skips the preceding part.

```
e.g: myfile.exe arguments1 | arguments2
```

Now in above code you can see the '|' the arguments which separates the two arguments and is required by myfile.exe to perform the operation but due to '|' character it skips the part before that and it gives me output as

```
'arguments2' is not recognized as internal or external, operable program or  batch file
```

How do I overcome this weird situation? I need '|' in my arguments list but process recognizes it as a OR.

Let me tell you guys the actual sitation. I am trying to extract a .cpio.gz archive using

```
gzip -d -c myarchive.cpio.gz | cpio -i
```

but due to | in the arguments I get output as

```
'cpio' is not recognized as internal or external, operable program or  batch file
```

but if I run the ported linux binary of gzip in ubuntu then it works exactly as i wanted because the linux terminal doesn't recognizes | as OR

Please I need help 
Thank you

Comment: | is shell (bash, cmd.exe etc.) syntax and not interpreted by QProcess. You'd need to start two QProcesses and shove the output from one to the other.

Comment: And how so? can you pls provide a example code? but I get that output using readyreadstandardoutput then? and same if I make its batch script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QProcess is doing what you want it to do: pass the whole line of command to the shell. The problem is you either don't have the second program `cpio` installed or it's not in the PATH environment of your Qt executable.

Does that line of command work when you enter it in (I assume) Windows command prompt?

BTW. The vertical bar character is a [pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29), not an argument to the .exe. That line of command actually invokes 2 separate programs.

Comment: cpio is not command, its a part of gzip and needed in arguments part when we unpack the archive. I dont want the vertical bar to be a pipeline but I want to be a part of args. Another thing I used this line even in cygwin and it worked then why cygwin or linux os didn't take it as pipeline?  Thanks

Comment: You were right! Thank you very much, I added cpio to env.variables and it worked!!! And that worked in linux  or cygwin because cpio is already in cygwins and linux's env.variables. Thanks a lot for making me learn. ignore my previous comment :D